# Who can help me to decrypt this code,base64

Tags: base64, uri, malformed, decodeuricomponent

var da = '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';

Comment: Check out: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not encryption, it is an encoding. There are many Base64 encoding functions, most languags supply a version in their associated libraries.

For online decoding see [Base 64 Encoder / Decoder](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html).

Comment: Can you help me with this problem.